# Command for copy line, open a new tab and paste line

Tags: vim, copy, paste

I am trying to write a vim command for following simple steps:

1. copy line under cursor
2. open a new tab
3. paste current line there

I tried following:

```
command Lnew y | tabnew | p
```

It copies and opens a new tab but does not paste. An error is shown at bottom:

```
empty buffer
```

However, the text is getting copied and is pasted if I press `p` in the new tab.

Why is this command not pasting copied text in new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem on the last command `p`. Instead of `p` you should use `pu` (`put`)

The `p` is command `:print`

Comment: Could also append a `1d` to remove the empty line

Comment: Yes, it works. But why should p work in same tab but not in new tab?

Comment: @mso new tab is a new empty buffer, so `:print` command cannot be executed, because it is empty. however your "same tab" is a non-empty buffer, that is why your `:print` cmd was executed without any errMsg.  But you should know, no matter `:print` has error or not, it is not the command you are looking for.